# Exposed queries and large datasets

Tags: kotlin-exposed

So when I execute a query in Exposed the return type is a SizedIterable. So how this this work for large datasets?

I created a small test case where I query 100.000 records and use a foreach to do some work on them. What I see in the memory consumption is that it gradually increases. Does this mean that eventually everything is in memory or do I just need to wait for garbage collection to kick in?

Any information on how this works in Exposed is welcome.

Comment: Do you use DSL or DAO to fetch records?

Comment: We are using the DSL (directly using the Tables)